# Drawing a german abacus as in the books of Adam Ries

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am teaching a course in history of mathematics and would like to draw something like the following:

[image]

The bullet points should be possible to draw on the lines and in between. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add the code you have tried so far?

Comment: You will find a tutorial for such shapes at the beginning of TikZ manual (the one dedicated to drawing algorithm). It is very well explained. All you have to do is to turn the white circles of its example into black.

Comment: Are the grid sizes fixed as in your MWE (4 horizontal lines and 2 vertical), or are they also variable?

Comment: Just a random thought: You can tweak `qcircuit`

Answer (score 25):

As you intend to draw "quite a few" of these you'll need a reasonable interface, so how about using code like this

```
  \abacus{{2,1},{1,1},{3,3,2},{},{4,2},{1}}
  \qquad
  \abacus{{1},{},{},{},{2},{1}}
```

to produce something like this:

[image]

The way that this works is that the `\abacus` command accepts a comma separated list of "abacus rows", which start from the bottom of the abacus and climb upwards. Each "abacus row" is itself a comma separated list that gives the number of balls in each column of the abacus, from left to right.

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  pics/abacus/.style = {
     code={
        \ifnum#1>0% have to treat 0 separately
          \foreach \ball [evaluate=\ball as \x
            using {(\ball-0.5-#1/2)*0.2}] in {1,...,#1} {
            \fill[black] (\x,0) circle (2.5pt);
          }
        \fi
    }
  },
  /tikz/abacus/.is family,% default values
  /tikz/abacus,
    xscale/.initial=1,  % default xscale=1 (no scaling)
    yscale/.initial=0.6,% default yscale=0.6
    columns/.initial=2, % default of 2 vertical rules
    rows/.initial=4     % default of 4 horizontal rules
}
% shortcut for accessing options
\newcommand\AbacusOption[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/abacus/#1}}

\newcommand\abacus[2][]{\tikzset{abacus, #1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
     xscale=\AbacusOption{xscale},
     yscale=\AbacusOption{yscale}
  ]
     \foreach \ypos in {1,...,\AbacusOption{rows}} {
     \draw(0,2*\ypos-1)--++(2*\AbacusOption{columns},0);
     }
     \foreach \xpos in {1,...,\AbacusOption{columns}} {
         \draw(2*\xpos, 0)--++(0,2*\AbacusOption{rows});
     }
     \foreach \row [count=\ypos] in {#2} {
         \foreach \col [count=\xpos] in \row {
             \draw (2*\xpos-1,\ypos) pic{abacus={\col}};
         }
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

  \abacus{{2,1},{1,1},{3,3,2},{},{4,2},{1}}
  \qquad
  \abacus{{1},{},{},{},{2},{1}}

\end{document}
```

The `\abacus` command accepts an optional argument that accepts a comma separated list of key-value pairs for changing the default number of rows and columns and the x and y scaling. For example,

```
\abacus[rows=2, columns=3, xscale=0.5, yscale=0.3]{{1,2,3,4},{0,3,1}}
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here I draw the first picture. You can draw the other based on this.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm]
\foreach \i in {1,2} \draw (\i,-.2) -- (\i,3.2);
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3} \draw (0,\i) -- (3,\i);
\foreach \x/\y in {
    .5/0,
    .4/2,
    .6/2,
    .5/2.5
} \fill (\x,\y) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]